# Calculator with radio button and if statement

Tags: javascript, radio-button, calculation

I am beginner in JavaScript and I am trying to write a code, but I can't. I want to write a calculator which includes radio button (with three choices)and when user chooses one of them it calculates different things, for example calculateing bmi or area of different shapes.

In the other words, I want to take 5 different numbers which user writes in fields. Then with this numbers and radio button selection, write a calculator.  Then I want to show the result to user.
Is it possible to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try and get an idea on how JavaScript works before moving onto something like this. I can't say it's advanced but considering you're a beginner, I think you should start off small, and understand the syntax of JavaScript better. There's tons of videos on YouTube on how to make a button calculator in JavaScript, and while I don't understand what exactly you're wanting, if you're really committed to this project you have in mind, maybe follow a YouTube tutorial on how to make a basic button calculator. You can then understand how radio buttons work and maybe experiment around with them in a way you want them to function.

Then, if you stumble upon some confusion or errors, you can paste your code snippet here and ask. Because right now, we can't write your code for you. This site is meant for asking programming questions while showing your code so people here and see where you're wrong and help you fix that error and then you can continue off with that new solution, while also learning something.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your advice is really helpful. I try it and after learning JavaScript, I will check my code here to fix errors.

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help.